# How to load dynamic editable Preferences

Tags: java, android, preferences

I am building an App with the new Navigation Drawer. Therefore i created several fragments, which are my app pages. One App page has a preference layout (extending preferencefragments). I have a listpreference loaded with dynamic values. I have setup another preference screen after this list.
Now what i want to do is, create depending on what the user selected from the list a dynamic generated preference layout with EditTextPreference.

I can't do this statically in xml, because i can't control how many EditTextPreference items are needed before the app compiles. 
Is there any way how i can set up a dynamic loadable preferences? Maybe completely without xml only in java?
Does android support a layout completely written in java at all? I don't need to take care where this will be saved. It should be loaded dynamically too.

Like (Pseudo-Code);

```
if (list.item3 == selected)
   show edittext1
   show edittext2
if (list.item1 == selected)
   show edittext8
   show edittext4
   show edittext9
```

See [screenshot](http://blechdose-live.de/download/kernel/test/app_screen.png) for a better explanation.

Any help here is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Custom

This is indeed possible and I do it on my app. In Java you need to make a custom class that extends `EditTextPreference`. Then override the methods you want to change. You can then add your custom view right into your xml like you would a normal `EditTextPreference`, except when you would create an xml element with the name of `EditTextPreference` you would do the full package name of your custom preference.

eg:

```
<com.your.name.CustomPreference
<!-- add all the andoid:x attributes you normaly would:-->
android:defaultValue="default string"
etc,
....
/>
```